# Subsequent file uploads to GCS failing to import into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

**Background**

1. I am relatively new to BigQuery ("BQ") & Google Cloud Storage ("GCS").
2. I've recently created a table in BQ that points to a file in GCS to ingest data.
3. The initial file upload to GCS properly imported data into BQ.
4. I've uploaded a new file into GCS (overwriting the prior file) and BQ is failing to import this new data into BQ for analysis.
5. Throughout this process, I have not received any errors in uploading of the data.

**Troubleshooting Attempted**

1. I've disabled BQ's data-cacheing to ensure that I am getting real results (and not results from previously executed SQL queries)
2. I've confirmed that the data structure/schema has not changed between the initial file upload to GCS and the latest file upload to GCS

**Questions**

1. Please confirm that BQ should automatically recognize newly uploaded data to GCS and import this data in real-time. If not real-time, am I able to manually trigger this ingestion of data?
2. Are there any configuration settings that I may be missing between BQ and GCS?

Comment: Understand the distinctions between LOADing a GCS file into BQ which is a copy of the data from GCS to BQ storage and defining an EXTERNAL table which is a reference to data stored in GCS.  Please supply details on "Created a table that points to a GCS file".  Please supply as many details as possible of what you have configured, what you have tested and what you have seen.   Based on loose description, I believe you want an external table pointing to GCS .. see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage

Answer (score 0):

Understanding BigQuery's Behavior:

No Real-Time Ingestion: BigQuery doesn't automatically import new data from GCS in real-time. You need to trigger data loading manually or configure automatic triggers.
Troubleshooting Steps:

Manually Trigger Data Loading:

Use the BigQuery web UI or API to initiate a load job.
Navigate to the table, click "Load" > "Load Data" and select the file from GCS.
Check for Automatic Triggers:

If you've set up automatic triggers, ensure they're functioning correctly.
Verify trigger conditions and logs for any errors.
Verify File Paths:

Ensure the table's external data source points to the correct file in GCS.
Double-check the file path for typos or inconsistencies.
Handle Overwritten Files:

If you're overwriting the same file, consider:
Appending data to an existing table instead of overwriting.
Using a different file name for each upload to trigger new load jobs.
Confirm Schema Compatibility:

Verify that the new file's schema matches the existing table schema.
Any mismatches will prevent data loading.
Address Permissions and Access:

Ensure BigQuery has the necessary permissions to access the GCS file.
Check IAM roles and bucket permissions.
Inspect Load Job History:

Review the load job history for any errors or warnings.
Identify specific issues that might be preventing data ingestion.
Additional Considerations:

File Versioning: If you're using GCS object versioning, exclude generation numbers from the file path in BigQuery.
Data Formats: Ensure the file format (CSV, JSON, Avro, etc.) is compatible with BigQuery and correctly parsed.
Data Types: Verify that data types in the file align with the table's schema.
Troubleshooting Resources: Refer to BigQuery documentation and community forums for further assistance.
If you continue to face issues, provide more details about your setup, error messages, and troubleshooting steps so I can offer more specific guidance.